# What is the best way to schedule job from Rails to EventMachine server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

I've created eventmachine app that perform some background job. I wonder what is the best way to send data from rails app to eventmachine app.

Currently Im thinking of using redis for this. Perhaps redis pub/sub functionality.

Is there any gem that can be used for this task?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the use case?

Comment: I've got a Apple Push Notifications sender, which is created using EM. I need to send notification on model callback in rails.

Comment: I would go with RabbitMQ or another messaging system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your needs I cannot give a precise answer but here are some leads:

- RabbitMQ as mentionned
- Redis with subscriptions or lists
- ZeroMQ (your rails application would open a connection directly to your background eventmachine process and then closes it when done)
- Raw TCP/UDP (if you are needs are really simple)

If you already have a redis server you can use its subscribe/publish feature or another thing I did which is to have a process do a brpop or blpop (the process will block on the call and take anything put in the queue right away) on a list and have your rails process push something to the list, it works pretty well.

Comment: What advantages ZeroMQ has against redis?

Comment: I just listed some options (and I just noticed the formatting was horrible), it has advantages over raw TCP/UDP sockets but of all the methods I listed I would prefer redis/RabbitMQ depending on what you already use.